# как передать в Myclass<T> как параметр ArrayList<MyObject>?

Tags: java, generics

Пишу простой конвертер  Json в объект. Написал такой класс. Всегда его получаю.

```
public class ResponseMessage<T> {

    private T result;
    private ResultCode resultCode;
    private String details;

    public ResponseMessage(T result, ResultCode resultCode, String details) {
        this.result = result;
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
        this.details = details;
    }

    public T getResult() {
        return result;
    }

    public void setResult(T result) {
        this.result = result;
    }

    public ResultCode getResultCode() {
        return resultCode;
    }

    public void setResultCode(ResultCode resultCode) {
        this.resultCode = resultCode;
    }

    public String getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(String details) {
        this.details = details;
    }
}
```

Плюс написал конвертер который из строки конвертнет в этот объект

```
public class Converter {
    private static Converter instance;
    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    public static Converter me() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Converter();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public <T> T getModel(String jsonStr, Class<T> type) {
        T t = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, type);
        return t;
    }

    public <T> List<T> getModelList(String jsonStr, Class<T[]> clazz) {
        T[] yourClassList = new Gson().fromJson(jsonStr, clazz);
        return Arrays.asList(yourClassList);
    }
}
```

И вот так пытаюсь вызвать

```
String s = RESTUtil.doPost(url, formData);
            ResponseMessage<MyObj> responseMessage = Converter.me().getModel(s,MyObj.class);
```

Но проблема в том что вместо MyObj.class у меня `ResponseMessage<ArrayList<CallDetail>>`

Тоесть я мне приходит строка в которой есть массив `CallDetail`. и я не могу сделать

```
 ResponseMessage<ArrayList<CallDetail>> responseMessage = Converter.me().getModel(s,ResponseMessage<ArrayList<CallDetail>>);
```

Я пробовал сделать так

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<ArrayList<CallDetail>>>() {}.getType();
            ResponseMessage<ArrayList<CallDetail>> model = Converter.me().getModel(s, listType);
```

а метод переделать так

```
public <T> T getModel(String jsonStr, Type type) {
        T t = gson.fromJson(jsonStr, type);
        return t;
    }
```

ничего не помогает. немного запутался. подскажите куда идти мне.

Comment: Дело в том, что на выходе ожидается у вас T, и объект ответа приёдет в том же формате. Т.е. если вы хотите, чтобы вернулся объект типа ResponseMessage - попробуйте переписать метод public <T> T getModel(String jsonStr, Class<T> type), чтобы он возвращал ResponseMessage<T>. Ну и реализацию внутри метода сделайте, чтобы было формирование ResponseMessage

Comment: Вы же из строки достаете `ResponseMessage`, поэтому создание типа будет выглядеть так: `new TypeToken<ResponseMessage<ArrayList<CallResult>>>(){}.getType()`